# Java: read a txt file with a matrix of letters, and search for words inside

Tags: java, crossword

I am trying to write a basic program in Java, and I'm using BlueJ.
I have to read a text file (input.txt) with a 15x15 matrix composed of letters, and look up words in it. These words are already known and written to the file input.txt.
Probably the txt file is already formatted in a way, because it forms the matrix and the search wordsh, but when I go to print I skip the first 7-8 rows (the matrix).

I am a beginner, and if possible I would like a little help on how to start this program, about how to read the file input.txt without omit the first few lines, and how to read the words in the matrix (the words already the know) and return the "position" or "direction" of the word (north, south, west, east, north-east, north-ov, south-e, etc...) like a crossword!

Thank you all ;)

The file input.txt is:

```
15
*
ESAFAMELBORPOZE
MTOTEQEVIRCSFCE
SDSTTNLHTIMSFUD
CITGSUGBANDTUOI
IVRUPORAMREFBCE
MEAIATGFTNOCSOR
MRTDDRDAENORRPO
ITEIEOINEMOIPOL
AIGANCTRPIPMRSO
UTIORETAEMOIEID
SIAAEUGAABRNZTA
CAMMINAVRAIEIIM
ARTSONOPRRTLOVM
ACATUDESNNONSOO
TALOBMABEAMVOSS
#
SMITH
TENENTE
FERMA
PROBLEMA
VORRA
STRATEGIA
AGOSTO
FRUTTA
NOIA
PAURA
GUIDI
SCIMMIA
CAMMINA
POSITIVO
SOMMA
SPADE
TRENO
TIRO
CORTO
MONTAGNE
CRIMINE
TUOI
LIBERI
SCRIVE
COMPAGNO
BAMBOLA
VAMPIRO
SEDUTA
BAND
DOLORE
DONO
PREZIOSO
DIVERTITI
BUFFO
NOSTRA
CUOCO
FASE
IDEE
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show us some of your code. @jmend Homework tag is deprecated. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated)

Comment: `NOSTRA` is in 12 horizontal (backwards) and `PREZIOSO` in 13 vertical. Now, if you have a **concrete** question about programming, and show us what you have done and tell which problem you have, maybe me may offer more help...

Comment: @jmend when you try to add the homework tag you get this message:  "This tag is OBSOLETE and is in the process of being removed. Please do NOT add this tag to questions."

Comment: I stopped at the beginning of the code, after reading the txt file.
The concrete problem is how to look up words, and then return the output to a file output.txt (indicating the row and column of the first letter, and north-south-etc ...)

Comment: I didn't know that the "homework" tag was deprecated. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I would store the data two times
1. lines as Strings -> you can search with `.indexOf`  [horizontal search]
2. columns as Strings  -> you can search with `.indexOf`  [vertical search]

Maybe I would even append with 'separation-character' all line to avoid iteration over each line for searching.
(same for the columns)

Comment: Just my two cents. How would you deal with diagonals or words written backwards? IM(ns)HO, `char[15][15]` gives better flexibility, and a String search is not that difficult to implement by yourself.

Comment: *backwards* can be handled by reverse the character order of the words to search , diagonals are a problem. You could store the data two more times as diagonals [I missed the requirement of diagonal matches, while I wrote my answer]

Answer (score -1):

One way to think about it would be to think of your matrix as a graph, and find the walk for each word.

A bad algorithm for doing it would be to find the starting (or ending) letter of a word, then parse the entire tree of connecting letters until you find it, and repeat until you find the word.

Start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28abstract_data_type%29), and it should lead you to some much better algorithms.

Comment: Appart from saying "hey, now it is a graph!", how it is supposed to help? Available operations would be the same, only that expressed as nodes and vertices instead of rows and columns.

Comment: For me the "Hey, it's a graph!" is an important step, because getting the terminology right will lead to infinitely more productive googleing and problem solving.

Comment: `Graph` or `Matrix` are both correct, depending of how you use it (I would use `table` FWIW). The question is: how does treating it as a graph help?